# Can we relocate the sqlaudit file to some other machine and view

Tags: sql-server

We have enabled security audit for `MSSQL DB` and generated the sqlaudit file. We are also able to view the content by running below command through SSMS:

```
SELECT   * 
    FROM     msdb.dbo.rds_fn_get_audit_file
                 ('D:\rdsdbdata\SQLAudit\*.sqlaudit'
                 , default
                 , default ) where action_id = 'LGIF';
```

But our requirement is to share this file with the security team so that they can view it locally in their server (which is different from the DB server for which sqlaudit file was created).

They are trying to run the same command after changing the file path but getting below error:

```
Msg 33224, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
The specified pattern did not return any files or does not represent a valid file share. Verify the pattern parameter and rerun the command.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is there anything we need to consider while sharing the audit file?

Answer (score 1):

Verify the SQL service account (or the users account if using other app) has permissions on the folder/share of the audit file.